# L1 convergence from convergence of the means

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

I want to prove the following result, but I can't get past a specific step and I'm not sure if I also need uniform integrability.

Suppose $X_n, X$ are nonnegative random variables with $E(X_n) \rightarrow E(X) < \infty$ and $P(X-X_n > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.  Then $E(|X_n-X|) \rightarrow 0$

---

**My attempt:**

Note that for large $n, X_n \in L^1$ so our expression is well defined.

$$E(|X - X_n|) = E((X - X_n)^+) - \underbrace{(E(X) - E(X_n))}_{\rightarrow 0}$$ so it sufficies to show that $E((X - X_n)^+) \rightarrow 0$.  The second statement we are allowed to assume in the question implies $(X-X_n)^+ \rightarrow 0$ in probability, so if we had uniform integrability of the $(X-X_n)^+$ random variables we would be done.  I can't proceed from here, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Is $P(X-X_n >\epsilon) \to 0$ supposed to be $P(|X-X_n| >\epsilon) \to 0$?

Comment: No, the question is stated in the format I gave here.  Does it work with your stated set of conditions?

Comment: Yes, I have a proof under that new condition.

Comment: Can I have a look at that proof?  I wouldn't know how to do it with the extra condition either

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy does it make a difference that the random variables are nonnegative?  I haven't used that anywhere so far (other than to say the expression is well defined for large $n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did most of the work, as you note (albeit with a missing factor of 2), we have:

$$E(|X - X_n|) = 2 E((X - X_n)^+) - \underbrace{(E(X) - E(X_n))}_{\rightarrow 0}$$

so, now, we just need to show that $E((X - X_n)^+) \rightarrow 0$. We have that $P(X > t) \geq P(X - X_n > t)$ for all $t$. Since both $(X - X_n)^+$ and $X$ are non-negative, and are integrable (the first one is dominated pointwise by second), we use the tail sum formula:

$$E((X - X_n)^+) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{t > 0} P(X - X_n > t) dt =  \int_{t > 0} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X - X_n > t) dt = 0$$

where we use DCT for the second equality (noting that $P(X > t)$ is our integrable function from the tail sum of $X$)

Comment: Applying DCT to the functions $Y_n(t) \equiv P(X - X_n > t)$ on the space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}), \text{Lebesgue measure})$ makes sense.  Thank you!